# PHP Curl with a file attachment

Tags: php, html, curl, web-scraping, scraper

I am trying to simulate a PHP cURL POST that requires a file upload.

Here is the HTML form from the website I am trying to POST TO: http://pastebin.com/X6Y0mmfP

The file I need to upload is "domains.txt" which can be found on the same directory as the script.

Using Live HTTP headers (firefox addon) I've retrieved this information:

```
POST to: http://www.majesticseo.com/reports/bulk-backlinks-upload
```

HTTP Headers:

```
Host: www.majesticseo.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://www.majesticseo.com/reports/bulk-backlink-checker
Cookie: _pk_id.2.d6bc=a607157d494109d4.1382175578.4.1388174858.1384073229.; RURI=reports%2Fbulk-    backlink-checker; _pk_ses.2.d6bc=*; STOK=Ox09WRWBeFCU3l3TAim86efmBa
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------210646678590
Content-Length: 1106
```

POST Content:

```
-----------------------------210646678590\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileType"\r\n
\r\n
SingleColumn\r\n
-----------------------------210646678590\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="indexType"\r\n
\r\n
F\r\n
-----------------------------210646678590\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ajaxLoadUrl"\r\n
\r\n
/reports/downloads/confirm-file-upload/backlinksAjax\r\n
-----------------------------210646678590\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="domains.txt"\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
\r\n
facebook.com\n
twitter.com\n
google.com\n
youtube.com\n
wordpress.org\n
adobe.com\n
blogspot.com\n
wikipedia.org\n
wordpress.com\n
linkedin.com\n
yahoo.com\n
amazon.com\n
flickr.com\n
w3.org\n
pinterest.com\n
apple.com\n
tumblr.com\n
myspace.com\n
microsoft.com\n
vimeo.com\n
digg.com\n
qq.com\n
stumbleupon.com\n
baidu.com\n
addthis.com\n
miibeian.gov.cn\n
statcounter.com\n
bit.ly\n
feedburner.com\n
nytimes.com\n
reddit.com\n
delicious.com\n
msn.com\n
macromedia.com\n
bbc.co.uk\n
weebly.com\n
blogger.com\n
icio.us\n
goo.gl\n
gov.uk\n
cnn.com\n
yandex.ru\n
webs.com\n
google.de\n
mail.ru\n
livejournal.com\n
sourceforge.net\n
go.com\n
imdb.com\n
jimdo.com\n
\r\n
-----------------------------210646678590--\r\n
```

In the manual browser upload, I am using domains.txt - which is also the file on the server (in the same directory as the script).

My script first logs in to then it attempts to make this request.
This is what I have tried to do so far, however it is not being accepted:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$post = array('fileType' => 'SingleColumn',
              'indexType' => 'F',
              'ajaxLoadUrl' => '/reports/downloads/confirm-file-upload/backlinksAjax',
              'file'=>'@'.realpath('./domains.txt') . ';filename=domains.txt'
              );
$post = http_build_query($post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.majesticseo.com/reports/bulk-backlinks-upload"); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  5 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       'majestic.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      'majestic.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.majesticseo.com/reports/bulk-backlink-checker');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl doesn't work very well with relative paths, please provide the full path.
**ex:**

realpath('/home/user/public_html/domains.txt')

Comment: Thank you for your reply - this did not seem to do the trick.. is there another parameter I am missing, or am I doing this file post incorrectly?

Comment: try increasing the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);` or completely remove it. What's the content of `majestic.txt`? does `majestic.txt` have write permissions ?

Comment: Hi there, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);` has been removed; although the page is not timing out. `majestic.txt` is writing correctly, it is the cookie file.

Comment: You can also try to provide the full URL here: `'ajaxLoadUrl' => '/reports/downloads/confirm-file-upload/backlinksAjax'`

Comment: The HTML form contains `<input type="hidden" name="ajaxLoadUrl" value="/reports/downloads/confirm-file-upload/backlinksAjax" />` which is not the full URL - is there anything I am doing wrong? If you take a look at the "POST Content" I posted, this is what a manual submission returns using a HTTP sniffer.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the function and how I generated the info for the request

```
function send_curl_request_with_attachment($method, $headers, $url, $post_fields) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
if($headers != "" && count($headers) > 0){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);  
return $result;}

$token_slams = "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token;
$authHeader = array(
$token_slams,
'Accept: application/form-data');

$schedule_path ='../../documents/' . $docs_record["document"];
$cFile = curl_file_create($schedule_path);

$post = array(
    'old_record' => $old_record,
    'employer_number' => $employer_number,
    'payment_date' => $payment_date,
    'fund_year' => $fund_year,
    'fund_month' => $fund_month,
    'employer_schedule'=> $cFile
);

send_curl_request_with_attachment("POST", $authHeader, $my_url, $post);
```